# multiple stored elements .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
nextimg = $('.index-slide-container img#' + next);
nextcaption = $('.index-slide-container .index-slide').filter('#'+next);

nextimg.css({
    'left':'100%',
    'z-index':'99'
});
nextcaption.css({
    'left':'100%',
    'z-index':'99'
});
```

I want to know if you can somehow combine/chain the two .css functions into one?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID (`next`)?

Comment: Yes I do - and Yes I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function:

```
nextimg.add(nextcaption).css({
    'left':'100%',
    'z-index':'99'
});
```

Comment: will this change `nextimg` so that it includes `nextcaption`?

Comment: If for instance I then called `.animate` on `nextimg`, would the elements stored in `nextcaption` be animated aswell?

Comment: @BillyMathews, no it wont, `.add()` returns their set so you have to do `nextimg = nextimg.add(nextcaption)` to use it elsewhere.